# NodeJS Humanized Multidimensional Array (Key Strings) like PHP

Tags: node.js

With Node JS, is it possible to set multi dimensional arrays separately, using key strings like in PHP ?

```
myArray[5]['age']      = 38;
myArray[5]['name']     = 'Jack';
myArray[5]['location'] = 'Australia';
```

I think this is confusing in Node JS:

```
var myArray = {};

myArray['usedId'] = new Array('Jack', 38, 'Australia');
```

because I had to do:

```
console.log (myArray[5]["0"]);
```

and I'd rather prefer to have a better control using:

```
console.log (myArray[5]['name']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP arrays are weird and represent many data structures at once.  An Array in JavaScript is closer to an traditional array although it is heterogeneous because of JavaScript's dynamic typing and probably other reasons.

Arrays in JavaScript use integer indices, but [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) in JavaScript represent key value pairs.  These are what you want to use.  You can have Arrays of Objects, and Object properties can contain arrays (and other objects).

```
myArray = [];
myArray[5] = {name: "Jack", age: "38", location: "Australia"};
console.log(myArray[5].name); // could also use ["name"]
```

Comment: Thanks, and then, how do I append "Email" value ?

Comment: @JackM. the access notation is both readable and writable.  You can include it in the `myArray[5] =` part, or you could do `myArray[5].Email = "email"`

Comment: Thanks again, just one more question: how would you get the myArray length ? In this case, would be 1 (key). The .length is giving me 0

Comment: @JackM. you shouldn't really do assignment like `myArray[5]` -- you should use `.push` or something to append to the array

Comment: How do your assign a key and value with .push ?

Comment: @JackM. `.push` is just to add objects to `myArray`, not to add properties to the objects it contains.

Comment: Sorry, I have absolutely no idea how to integrate .push in a multi dimensional array. I am new to Node JS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59290/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-jack-m).

Answer (score 2):

Use an object, not an array:

```
myArray[5] = {
               name: 'Jack',
               age: 38,
               location: 'Australia'
             };
```

This will cause `console.log (myArray[5]['name']);` to work perfectly.

Also, your `myArray` is an object (`{}`), not an array (`[]`).